# if else pdf file exist codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, if-statement

I want to open pdf file from my directory. and if file exist, it will open it from my directory and it works. but, if the pdf file doesn't exist, i want it returns test like in my code and it still doesn't works. please help me. Thanks

The code view is below :

```
<?php
if ($this->pos != 1) {
    if (!$id) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" >
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="use_form" value="1"/>make a quotation form after save this transaction</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if (!$quotation) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <a href="javascript:show_popUp('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/quotation/<?php echo $id; ?>')"> Create Quotation</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php  $file = base_url()."quotation/".$quotation.".pdf";   ?>
        <?php if(file_exists($file)) {

                $file = $file;
            } 
            else {
                $file = "test";
                } ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>quotation/<?php echo $quotation;?>.pdf">View Quotation </a>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <a href="javascript:show_popUp('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/edit_quotation/<?php echo $id; ?>')"> Revised Quotation</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
} ?>
```

the controller code is below
`

```
protected $active_user;

function __construct() {
    parent::Controller();
    $this->utility->cek_session();

    $this->active_user = $this->session->userdata('active_user');

    $this->load->library('form');
    $this->load->model('service_tracking/trans_service_model');
    $this->load->library('table_generator');
    $this->load->model('service_tracking/service_status_model');
    $this->load->model('service_tracking/quotation_model');
}

function index() {

    $data['content'] = "template/frm_filter";

    $data['control_panel'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/control_panel/";
    $data['title'] = "Service Tracking System > <a href='manage_trans'>Manage Trans</a> > In House Service Transaction";

    $data['controller'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/";
    $data['form'] = "service_tracking/trans_service/form/";
    $data['table'] = $data['controller'] . "table";
    $data['report'] = true;

    $this->load->view('template/main_service', $data);
}

function pending() {


    $data['content'] = "template/frm_filter";

    $data['control_panel'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/control_panel/";
    $data['title'] = "Service Tracking System > <a href='../manage_trans'>Manage Trans</a> > (Pending) In House Service Transaction";

    $data['controller'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/";
    $data['form'] = "service_tracking/trans_service/form/";
    $data['table'] = $data['controller'] . "table/pending";
    $data['report'] = true;

    $this->load->view('template/main_service', $data);
}

function form($fill = '', $java = '') {
    $data['action'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/save";

    if (!empty($fill)) {
        $fill = $this->trans_service_model->fill_data($fill);
        $data['action'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/edit";
        $data['id'] = $fill['id'];
    }

    if ($java == 'add') {
        $data['java'] = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.do_filter();</script>";
        $data['java'] .= "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
    }
    if ($java == 'use_form') {
        $data['java'] = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.do_filter();</script>";
        $data['java'] = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.show_quotation('" . $fill['id'] . "');</script>";

        $data['java'] .= "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
    }

    $pos = $this->session->userdata('active_user');

    $rule = $this->service_status_model->get_rule($pos['id_position']);

    $data['serial_no'] = $this->form->choose('serial_no', $fill['id_ticket_detail'], $fill['no_serial']);

    $data['quotation'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/quotation";
    $data['content'] = "service_tracking/trans_service";
    $data['controller'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/";
    $data['title'] = "IN HOUSE TRANSACTION FORM";

    $radio = array(
        array(
            'value' => 'waranty',
            'name' => 'Waranty'
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'no_waranty',
            'name' => 'No Waranty'
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'under_contract',
            'name' => 'Under Contract'
        )
    );

    $data['service_desc'] = $this->form->radio('service_desc', $radio, $fill['service_desc']);

    $data['use_new'] = false;

    $setting = array(
        'db' => 'st_service_status',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'status_name',
        'menu_id' => '1'
    );

    $tekhnisi = array(
        'db' => 'st_tekhnisi',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'name');

    $data['id_status'] = $this->form->drop_down_db1('id_status', $fill['id_status_service'], $setting);
    $data['id_tekhnisi'] = $this->form->drop_down_db('id_tekhnisi', $fill['id_tekhnisi'], $tekhnisi);


    $data['RMA_date'] = $this->form->calendar('RMA_date', $fill['RMA_date']);
    $data['RMA_return_date'] = $this->form->calendar('RMA_return_date', $fill['RMA_return_date']);
    $data['RMA_number'] = $this->form->text_box('RMA_number', $fill['RMA_number']);
    $data['action_in'] = $this->form->text_box('action_in', $fill['action_in']);

    $data['customer_return_date'] = $this->form->calendar('customer_return_date', $fill['customer_return_date']);
    $data['sparepart_memo'] = $this->form->text_area('sparepart_memo', $fill['sparepart_memo'], 50, 5);

    $data['quotation'] = $this->quotation_model->cek_form($fill['id']);

    $data['id_ticket'] = $fill['id_ticket_detail'];

    $data['id'] = $fill['id'];
    $data['unique_id'] = $this->form->hidden('unique_id', $this->utility->session_id());

    $rule = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'serial_no',
            'name' => 'SERIAL NUMBER'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'id_status',
            'name' => 'SERVICE STATUS'
        )
    );
    $data['cek'] = $this->form->form_rule($rule);

    $data['width'] = 600;

    $this->load->view('template/form', $data);
}

function cancel() {
    $this->form();
}

function table($param = null) {
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

    $page = $sort = $dir = '';
    $setting = array();

    if($param)
        $param = true;

    if (isset($_POST['page']))
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    if (isset($_POST['sort']))
        $sort = $_POST['sort'];
    if (isset($_POST['dir']))
        $dir = $_POST['dir'];
    if (isset($_POST['limit']))
        $limit = $_POST['limit'];
    if (isset($_POST['setting'])) {
        $setting = $_POST['setting'];
        $limit = $_POST['limit'] = 'all';
    }

    $table_setting = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'unique_id',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'customer_name',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'product_name',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'no_serial',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'ticket_date',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'status_name',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'standard_date',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'customer_return_date',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'update_date',
            'type' => 'none'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'is_quoted',
            'type' => 'check'
        )
    );

    $list = $table_setting;
    $header = array('Ticket No.', 'Company Name', 'Product Name', 'No. Serial', 'Date In', 'Status', 'Estimated Finish Day(s)', 'Engineer', 'Customer Return Date', 'Update Date', 'Quoted');
    $total = $this->trans_service_model->totalData($setting, $param);

    if (!$_POST['is_report']) {
        $return = $this->trans_service_model->all_data($page, $sort, $dir, $limit, $setting, $param);

        $return = $this->table_generator->tableGenerator($return, $list, $header, $total, 'no_serial');
        $_POST['setting'] = "";
        echo $return;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['setting'] = $setting;
        $_SESSION['sort'] = $sort;
        $_SESSION['dir'] = $dir;
        $_SESSION['list'] = $list;
        $_SESSION['header'] = $header;
        $_SESSION['total'] = $total;

        $year = "any";
        $period = "any";
        $month = "any";

        if ($setting['year'])
            $year = $setting['year'];

        if ($setting['period']) {
            if ($setting['period'] == 1)
                $add = "st";
            else if ($setting['period'] == 2)
                $add = "nd";
            else if ($setting['period'] == 3)
                $add = "rd";
            else
                $add = "th";

            $period = $setting['period'] . "<sup>" . $add . "</sup>";
            $month = "-";
        }

        if ($setting['month']) {
            $month_array = array('January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
            $month = $month_array[($setting['month'] - 1)];
            $period = "-";
        }

        $title = "<table cellpadding='3' border='1' cellspacing = '-1' width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2' valign='middle' align='center'>
                            <div style='font-size : 25px'><b>Service Transaction Report</b></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='10%'>Year</td>
                        <td width='90%'>" . $year . "</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Month</td>
                        <td>" . $month . "</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Period</td>
                        <td>" . $period . "</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>";

        $_SESSION['title'] = $title;

        if ($_POST['is_report'] == "pdf")
            $type = "index/trans_service";
        else if ($_POST['is_report'] == "excel")
            $type = "excel/trans_service";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"
        . "$('#frame_executor').attr('src', base_url + 'index.php/report/general/" . $type . "');"
        . "</script>";
    }
}

function control_panel() {
    $merk_setting = array(
        'db' => 'st_merk',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'merk_name'
    );

    $type_setting = array(
        'db' => 'st_product_type',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'type_name'
    );

    $status_setting = array(
        'db' => 'st_service_status',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'status_name'
    );
    $date_start = array(
        'db' => 'st_trans_service',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'entry_date'
    );
    $date_end = array(
        'db' => 'st_trans_service',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'service_date'
    );

     $tekhnisi_setting = array(
        'db' => 'st_tekhnisi',
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'tekhnisi_name'
    );

    $id_merk = $this->form->drop_down_db('id_merk', '', $merk_setting, "onchange='do_filter()'");
    $id_product_type = $this->form->drop_down_db('id_product_type', '', $type_setting, "onchange='do_filter()'");
    $id_status = $this->form->drop_down_db('id_status', '', $status_setting, "onchange='do_filter()'");
    $start = $this->form->calendar('entry_date', '', $date_start, "onchange='do_filter()'");
    $end = $this->form->calendar('service_date', '', $date_end, "onchange='do_filter()'");
    $id_tekhnisi = $this->form->drop_down_db('id_tekhnisi', '', $tekhnisi_setting, "onchange='do_filter()'");

    $filter = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Year',
            'content' => $this->form->tahun('year', '', "onchange='do_filter()'")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Month',
            'content' => $this->form->bulan('month', '', "onchange='do_filter()'")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Period',
            'content' => $this->form->period('period', "onchange='do_filter()'")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Product Type',
            'content' => $id_product_type
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Brand',
            'content' => $id_merk
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Product Name',
            'content' => $this->form->text_box('product_name', '', '35', " onkeyup='do_filter()' ")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Customer',
            'content' => $this->form->text_box('customer_name', '', '35', " onkeyup='do_filter()' ")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Status',
            'content' => $id_status
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Date Start',
            'content' => $start
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Date End',
            'content' => $end
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Serial No.',
            'content' => $this->form->text_box('no_serial', '', '30', " onkeyup='do_filter()' ")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Ticket No.',
            'content' => $this->form->text_box('unique_id', '', '30', " onkeyup='do_filter()' ")
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Engineer Name',
            'content' => $id_tekhnisi
        ),
    );

    $data['filter'] = $this->form->generate_filter($filter);
    $data['data_management'] = true;

    $this->load->view('template/platform', $data);
}

function delete() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    foreach ($id as $id_a)
        $this->trans_service_model->delete_data($id_a);

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>do_filter();</script>";
}

function edit() {

    $id_status = $_POST["id_status"];
    $id_ticket_detail = $_POST["serial_no"];
    $service_desc = $_POST['service_desc'];
    $RMA_date = $_POST['RMA_date'];
    $RMA_return_date = $_POST['RMA_return_date'];
    $RMA_number = $_POST['RMA_number'];
    $customer_return_date = $_POST['customer_return_date'];
    $action_in = $_POST['action_in'];
    $sparepart_memo = $_POST['sparepart_memo'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id_tekhnisi = $_POST['id_tekhnisi'];

    $array = array(
        $id_ticket_detail,
        $id_status,
        $service_desc,
        $RMA_date,
        $RMA_return_date,
        $RMA_number,
        $customer_return_date,
        $action_in,
        $sparepart_memo,
        $id
    );

    $update_tekhnisi = array(
        $id_tekhnisi, $id_ticket_detail
    );

    $sess = $this->session->userdata('active_user');
    $this->pos = $sess['id_position'];



    $this->trans_service_model->edit_data($array);
    if ($this->pos != 1) {
        $this->trans_service_model->edit_tekhnisi($update_tekhnisi);
    }




    $id_detail = $this->trans_service_model->edit_data($array);




    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>do_filter();close_form();</script>";
}

function save() {
    $id_status = $_POST["id_status"];
    $id_ticket_detail = $_POST["serial_no"];
    $service_desc = $_POST['service_desc'];
    $RMA_date = $_POST['RMA_date'];
    $RMA_return_date = $_POST['RMA_return_date'];
    $RMA_number = $_POST['RMA_number'];
    $customer_return_date = $_POST['customer_return_date'];
    $action_in = $_POST['action_in'];
    $sparepart_memo = $_POST['sparepart_memo'];

    $array = array(
        $id_ticket_detail,
        $this->active_user['id'],
        $id_status,
        date("Y-m-d"),
        date("h:i:s"),
        $service_desc,
        $RMA_date,
        $RMA_return_date,
        $RMA_number,
        $customer_return_date,
        $action_in,
        $sparepart_memo,
        $_POST['unique_id']
    );
    $this->trans_service_model->add_data($array);

    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (!$_POST['use_form'])
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>do_filter();close_form();</script>";
        else {
            $id = $this->trans_service_model->get_id($_POST['unique_id']);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>do_filter();close_form();show_quotation('" . $id . "')</script>";
        }
    } else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>do_filter();close_form();</script>";

    // bikin pdf
    $this->send_email($id_ticket_detail, $id_status);
}

function uniq_code() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_last_id();
    $unique++;

    if (strlen($unique) == 1)
        $unique = '0' . $unique;

    $unique = "Q" . date("ymd") . $unique;

    return $unique;
}

function quotation($id = '', $fill = '', $java = '') {
    $data['action'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/save_quotation";

    $data['form'] = "service_tracking/quotation_form";
    $data['controller'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/";
    $data['title'] = "SERVICE QUOTATION FORM";

    $data['use_new'] = false;

    $data['no_quotation'] = $this->uniq_code();

    $data['id_trans_service'] = $this->form->hidden('id_trans_service', $id);
    $data['sales_code'] = $this->form->text_box('sales_code', '', 20);

    $data['problem'] = $this->form->text_area('problem');
    $data['note'] = $this->form->text_area('note');
    $data['action_taken'] = $this->form->text_area('action_taken');

    $data['service_charge'] = $this->form->number('service_charge', '', 12);

    $data['part_no'] = $this->form->text_box('part_no', '', 13);
    $data['desc'] = $this->form->text_box('desc', '', 35);
    $data['qty'] = $this->form->number('qty', '', 5);
    $data['price'] = $this->form->number('price', '', 12);
    $data['discount'] = $this->form->number('discount', '', 3);

    $setting = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'IDR',
            'value' => 'IDR'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'USD',
            'value' => 'USD'
        )
    );
    $data['rate'] = $this->form->drop_down('rate', $setting);
    $data['service_charge_rate'] = $this->form->drop_down('service_charge_rate', $setting);

    $this->load->view('template/form2', $data);
}

function save_quotation() {
    $detail = array();

    if ($_POST['detail'])
        $detail = $_POST['detail'];

    $out = array(
        'part_no' => $_POST['part_no'],
        'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
        'qty' => $_POST['qty'],
        'price' => $_POST['price'],
        'rate' => $_POST['rate'],
        'discount' => $_POST['discount']

    );

    array_push($detail, $out);

    $id_tekhnisi = $this->session->userdata('active_user');
    $id_tekhnisi = $id_tekhnisi['id'];

    $header = array(
        $_POST['id_trans_service'],
        $_POST['no_quotation'],
        $_POST['problem'],
        $_POST['action_taken'],
        $_POST['remark'],
        $_POST['payment'],
        $_POST['service_charge'],
        $_POST['service_charge_rate'],
        $_POST['service_location'],
        $_POST['note'],
        date('Y-m-d'),
        $_POST['sales_code'],
        $id_tekhnisi
    );

    $this->quotation_model->add_header($header);
    $id = $this->quotation_model->get_id($_POST['no_quotation']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($detail); $i++) {
        $detail[$i]['ammount'] = $detail[$i]['qty'] * $detail[$i]['price'];
        $detail[$i]['id_header_quotation'] = $id;

        $this->quotation_model->add_detail($detail[$i]);
    }

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.opener.create_pdf('" . $id . "');
            window.opener.do_filter();
            window.opener.close_form();
            window.close();
          </script>";
}

function sales_code() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_sales_code();

    return $unique;
}

function problem() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_problem();

    return $unique;
}

function action_taken() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_action_taken();

    return $unique;
}

function service_charge() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_service_charge();

    return $unique;
}

function note() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_note();

    return $unique;
}

function no_part() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_no_part();

    return $unique;
}

function description() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_description();

    return $unique;
}

function qty() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_qty();

    return $unique;
}

function price() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_price();

    return $unique;
}

function disc() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_disc();

    return $unique;
}

function uniq_code_rev() {
    $unique = $this->quotation_model->get_last_id();
    $unique++;

    if (strlen($unique) == 1)
        $unique = '0' . $unique;

    $unique = "Q" . date("ymd") . $unique . " rev- " . $this->quotation_model->get_no_quotation();

    return $unique;
}

function edit_quotation($id = '', $fill = '', $java = '') {

    $data['action'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/save_quotation";

    $data['form'] = "service_tracking/quotation_form_1";
    $data['controller'] = base_url() . "index.php/service_tracking/trans_service/";
    $data['title'] = "EDIT SERVICE QUOTATION FORM";

    $data['use_new'] = false;
    $data['no_quotation'] = $this->uniq_code_rev();
    $data['id_trans_service'] = $this->form->hidden('id_trans_service', $id);
    $data['sales_code'] = $this->sales_code();
    $data['problem'] = $this->problem();
    $data['note'] = $this->note();
    $data['action_taken'] = $this->action_taken();
    $data['service_charge'] = $this->form->number('service_charge', '', 12);
    $data['part_no'] = $this->no_part();
    $data['description'] = $this->description();
    $data['qty'] = $this->qty();
    $data['price'] = $this->price();
    $data['discount'] = $this->disc();

    $setting = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'IDR',
            'value' => 'IDR'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'USD',
            'value' => 'USD'
        )
    );
    $data['rate'] = $this->form->drop_down('rate', $setting);
    $data['service_charge_rate'] = $this->form->drop_down('service_charge_rate', $setting);
    $this->load->view('template/form2', $data);
    var_dump($data);
    exit;

}

function send_email($id_ticket, $id_status) {
    $arr_day = array('Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu', 'Minggu');
    $arr_month = array('Januari', 'Febuari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'November', 'Desember');

    $this->load->library('email');

    $data = $this->trans_service_model->get_emaildata($id_ticket);
    $status = $this->trans_service_model->get_status($id_status);

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.push.mobi';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 25;
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'yani@sgp-dkp.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'yaniya';
    $config['priority'] = 1;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('yani@sgp-dkp.com', 'Duta Kalingga Pratama');
    $this->email->to(array($data['customer_email'], $data['PIC_email']));

    $this->email->subject('Service Status Update');

    $message = "
    Dear Customer, <br/><br/>
    Berikut ini kami informasikan status dari <b>"
            . $data['type_name'] . " " . $data['merk_name'] . "
    " . $data['product_name'] . "  </b> : <br/><br/>" .
            "Ticket No  : " . $data['unique_id'] . " <br/>
    Serial No   : " . $data['no_serial'] . " <br/>
    Tgl masuk   : " . $data['entry_date'] . "<br/>
    <br/><br/>
    Status pada hari ini " . $arr_day[date("w")] . ", " . date("d") . " " . $arr_month[(date("n") - 1)] . " " . date("Y") . " adalah    : " . $status . "  <br/>
    untuk informasi lebih lanjut hubungi kami di nomor +62 21 641 0730, atau via email di helpdesk@sgp-dkp.com.";

    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
}

function send_email_engineer($id_ticket, $id_status) {
    $arr_day = array('Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu');
    $arr_month = array('Januari', 'Febuari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'November', 'Desember');

    $this->load->library('email');

    $data = $this->trans_service_model->get_emaildata_test($id_ticket);
    $status = $this->trans_service_model->get_status($id_status);

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.push.mobi';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 25;
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'yani@sgp-dkp.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'yaniya';
    $config['priority'] = 1;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('yani@sgp-dkp.com', 'Duta Kalingga Pratama');
    $this->email->to(array($data['email']));

    $this->email->subject('In House Repair');
    $message = "
    Dear " . $data['name'] . ", <br/><br/>
    Anda memiliki tanggung jawab untuk melakukan In House Repair, <br/>
    berikut detailnya : <br/><br/>
    Nama Customer : <b>" . $data['customer_name'] . "</b><br/>
    Nama Barang : <b>" . $data['type_name'] . " " . $data['merk_name'] . "
    " . $data['product_name'] . "</b><br/>
     Serial No  : <b>" . $data['no_serial'] . " </b><br/>
     Ticket No  : <b>" . $data['unique_id'] . " </b><br/>
     Remarks    : <b>" . $data['id_status'] . "</b>";


    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();}}`
```

Comment: Note: This `parent::Controller();` should be `parent::__construct()` explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So really your question is "How do I detect if a File exists or not?"

In PHP there is an inbuilt function called file_exists()

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/your.pdf';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    // Display the PDF
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    // Show some message about the file not existing.
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

So you need to incorporate that into your code.